# What does 私が心の底から面白いと笑って読める小説 mean?

Tags: meaning, particles, particle-と

> 私が心の底から面白いと笑って読める小説をたくさん手に入れることだった。

Does the と quote the 面白い？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this と is a quotative-と. と can be used without verbs like 思う and 考える (see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48032/5010) for example), but I think it's okay to think 笑う is directly taking the と-clause in this case. Either way, a literal translation of 私が心の底から面白いと笑って読める小説 would be "novels which I can read (while) smiling (while) thinking (it's) amusing from the bottom of my heart".