What does 気まぐれ here mean?

俺がげいだって伝えた時も反応薄かったし。気まぐれだったかと
そこまでいい加減じゃないよ!
The first line could be translated as "When I told I was gay too, your reaction very weak.
And the other character points out
"I'm not that irresponsible!"
however, I'm confused about 気まぐれ here. From what I know "気まぐれ" means "whim". Is he talking about how the other character was? "I thought you were fickle"?  From context, my reading would be maybe "Maybe YOU thought I was being 気まぐれ"? But I'm not sure it's correct.

大辞林 defines this sense of 気まぐれ as follows:

気が変わりやすいこと。その時々の気分や思いつきで物事を行うこと。また，そのようなさまや，そういう人。「―な男」「いちじの―」

These meanings can be conveyed in English by a variety of nouns, such as "whim," "caprice," "capriciousness," "impulsiveness," "inconstancy," and "fancy" (as in "just a passing fancy"); and adjectives, such as "capricious," "fickle," "changeable," "inconstant," etc.
In this case, though, a much more idiomatic option would be to use the word "phase," as in "just going through a phase" or "just a phase one [is/was] going through."
As in

Even when I told you I was gay, you didn't have much of a reaction. You thought maybe it was just a phase I was going through.


Contextually, I understand it but I'm not sure what he omitted after the と

@Kawase_K, this is one of those cases where と follows a phrase (here, 気まぐれだったのか) that tells us what someone thinks or thought. It's basically equivalent to と思って, but I don't think it's quite accurate to say that 思って has been omitted, because this is a usage in which と conveys that meaning clearly and fully on its own. You can read more at https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/48032/か-と-particles-with-a-non-quotation-verb and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24583/use-of-quote-marker-と-before-unusual-verbs
